# Нужна ли запятая в нижеприведенном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Все, как и положено, в русской сказке». Нужна ли запятая после «положено»? Склоняюсь, что да.

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта пунктуации:

Спектакль. В нём герои, костюмы, музыка — всё как и положено в русской сказке (сказуемое «всё как и положено в русской сказке» не разделяется запятыми)
Спектакль. В нём герои, костюмы, музыка — всё, как и положено в русской сказке (сравнительный оборот, смысл фразы меняется с «у нас есть то, что будто из русской сказки» на «у нас есть всё, что можно, прямо как в русской сказке»)

Comment: Хмм.... то есть есть спектакль...в нем есть все, что присуще русской сказке....герои, костюмы, музыка и т.д.

Comment: @flossyU отредактировал ответ с оглядкой на ваше дополнение

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, потому что сочетание ‟как и положено” является сказуемым.

Comment: Вот это как раз самое спорное. У Розенталя ни одного примера с И. Частица И способствует логическому ударению на "всё" и постановке запятой.

Comment: Да тут вообще нельзя ответить, так как нужен контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Пропуск "так" в "так... как **и**" похож на стилистическую ошибку. Или надо убрать частицу И:
*Всё как положено в русской сказке.* || Так точно запятые не нужны.

Ни одного примера у Розенталя с таким пропуском.

Частица И способствует логическому ударению на "всё" и постановке запятой, иначе звучит как-то не по-русски. В справочнике Лопатина есть такое правило:
**Всегда выделяется оборот, начинающийся сочетанием "как и".**
Но и с запятой не звучит нормально — без "так".

Раз у нас не сказка, а спектакль, то "*в русской сказке*" следует включить в сравнительный оборот (без запятой) — потому что сравниваем со сказкой (в обороте), а не говорим о сказке (вне оборота).